# Python kivy game: how can I make a rectangle collide with a quad

Tags: python, kivy, collision-detection, game-physics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHAGK.jpg)I am creating a game but I can't make rectangle collide with the quad shape. It collides when the rectangle is at the middle of the quad and at the right side of the quad but if I move the rectangle to the left side of the quad it does not collide any more. It just the edge of the rectangle goes out or even reaches the left of the quad it will stop colliding

```
rect = None

rect_coordinates = [(0, 0), (0, 0)]

nb_b = 100

brick = []

brick_coordinates = []

def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.init_vertical_line()

    self.init_horizontal_line()

    self.init_brick()

    self.init_ship()

    self.init_rect()

    self.generate_brick_coordinates()

    Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)

def init_rect(self):

    with self.canvas:

        Color(0, 1, 0)

        self.rect = Rectangle()

def update_rect(self):

    pos_x = self.movement

    pos_y = self.height/1.923

    size_x = self.width/15

    size_y = self.height/25

    self.rect_coordinates[0] = (pos_x, pos_y)

    self.rect_coordinates[1] = (size_x, size_y)

    self.rect.pos = (self.rect_coordinates[0])

    self.rect.size = (self.rect_coordinates[1])

def collided(self):

    for i in range(0, len(self.brick_coordinates)):

        bi_x, bi_y = self.brick_coordinates[i]

        if bi_y < self.current_y_loop:

            return False

        if self.ball_collide_brick(bi_x, bi_y):

            return True

    return False

def ball_collide_brick(self, bi_x, bi_y):

    x_min, y_min = self.get_brick_coordinate(bi_x, bi_y)

    x_max, y_max = self.get_brick_coordinate(bi_x+1, bi_y+1)

    for i in range(0, 1):

        px, py = self.rect_coordinates[i]

        if x_min <= px <= x_max and y_min <= py <= y_max:

            return True

    return False

def init_brick(self):

    with self.canvas:

        Color(1, 1, 1)

        for i in range(0, self.nb_b):

            self.brick.append(Quad())

def get_line_x_from_index(self, index):

    central_x = self.width / 2

    spacing = self.v_line_space * self.width

    offset = index - 0.5

    line_x = central_x + offset * spacing

    return line_x

def get_line_y_from_index(self, index):

    spacing_y = self.h_line_space * self.height

    line_y = index * spacing_y - self.current_y_offset

    return line_y

def get_brick_coordinate(self, bi_x, bi_y):

    bi_y = bi_y - self.current_y_loop

    x = self.get_line_x_from_index(bi_x)

    y = self.get_line_y_from_index(bi_y)

    return x, y

def update_brick(self):

    for i in range(0, self.nb_b):

        bricks = self.brick[i]

        brick_c = self.brick_coordinates[i]

        x_min, y_min = self.get_brick_coordinate(brick_c[0], brick_c[1])

        x_max, y_max = self.get_brick_coordinate(brick_c[0] + 1, brick_c[1] + 1)

        x1, y1 = self.transform(x_min, y_min)

        x2, y2 = self.transform(x_min, y_max)

        x3, y3 = self.transform(x_max, y_max)

        x4, y4 = self.transform(x_max, y_min)

        bricks.points = [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4]
```

Comment: Please include more details on your issue: do the shapes collide only sometimes? never? Where do you think the culprit is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It collides when the rectangle is at the middle of the quad and at the right side of the quad but if I move the rectangle to the left side of the quad it does not collide any more